# modify S3 Generics with dots using formals

Tags: r

In my path to a better understanding of R language, I'm trying to modify base functions like `mean()`, `sd()`, `sum()` to use the argument `na.rm = TRUE` by default.

I think that one way to perform that would be to use the formals() function.

I tried:

```
m <- mean
formals(m) <- alist(x = , na.rm = TRUE, ... = )
m(c(12, 16, NA))
```

I think that it doesn't work because of the S3 method dispatch. How would you modify that code to make it return 14 and not NA?

I know that I can do it with a code like:

```
s <- function(...){
   sum(..., na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

But it does not satisfy my curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

There are some `mean` so for example if you want to overwrite `mean` for `numeric`
( its only idea -- and may be there is other way)

1) Find needed mean

```
> methods(mean)
[1] mean.Date     mean.default  mean.difftime mean.IDate*   mean.POSIXct  mean.POSIXlt  mean.times*  
see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
```

2) Overwrite

```
m=mean.default
formals(m) <- alist(x = , trim=0,na.rm = TRUE, ... = )
```

Test

```
> x=c(12, 16, NA)
> m(x)
[1] 14
```

Or may be better would be create one more mean ( with new class ) like

```
mean.myclass=mean.default
formals(mean.myclass) <- alist(x = , trim=0,na.rm = TRUE, ... = )

x=c(12, 16, NA)
class(x) <- append("myclass",class(x))
mean(x)
y=c(12, 16, NA)
mean(y)
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to pass the argument to the generic function?

Comment: I dont know, may be some one have better idea and post it as answer